# Job is not failing in pentaho which i read it through VFS when the file is not available in S3

Tags: pentaho-spoon

i have a job in pentaho which read the data from S3 through virtual file system. So the extracted data from source is not regular as its a adhoc basis. Ideally i had to write a loop condition from today's date to the date which matches in S3. 
When the file is not available in s3 then i gave a failure condition to parse it through loop condition, but it is not failing. Could anyone suggest the way?

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: If it s not failing, the file exist but is empty. I am right ? But where do you find the date in the S3 ? From the file name ? In a field of one file? Please explain better what you did and what you want to achieve.